# Sometimes it saves sometimes not in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-2.7

i have a problem in this method when i try to call it from another file it saves perfectly in the db and the values are updated (the points are added to the contractor) but i don't understand how when i call it in another file (other than the first one ) it only save the value inside the method but once it was out of the method the value wasn't saved it returned back (checked by printing )

```
def add_points_cont(contractor_id , action_name):
    contractor = Contractor.objects.get(id=contractor_id)
    action = Action.objects.get(name=action_name)
    toBeAdded = action.points
    totalPoints = contractor.points+toBeAdded
    contractor.points = totalPoints
    contractor.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may pass the method another parameter

`def add_points_cont(contractor=None , action_name):`

you pass the contractor into method

Comment: You mean to change from passing the ID to passing the `Contractor` object, I believe? (Your answer is very difficult to comprehend.)

Comment: i passed to the method the contractor Object itself and it worked!! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are asking, but it sounds like you are reading back a cached value from the database. In django [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), which means that you may not be seeing the latest updated values from the database, and this is normal.